# NGINX rewriting subfolder when folder already rewritten?

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have

```
/site/clients/anything
```

rewriting to

```
/site/clients/index.php?action=$1
```

however i also want to rewrite

```
/site/clients/verify/anything
```

to

```
/site/clients/verify/index.php?VID=$1
```

Things i've tried

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    rewrite ^/site/clients/verify/(.+)$ /site/clients/verify/index.php?VID=$1;
    rewrite ^/site/clients/^(?!login|sign-up|verify\/.*$).*$ /site/clients/index.php?action=$1;
    index index.php index.html;
}

location ~ /site/clients/verify/(.+)$ {
    rewrite ^/site/clients/verify/(.+)$ /site/clients/verify/index.php?VID=$1;
}

location ~ /site/clients/^(?!login|sign-up|verify\/.*$).*$ {
    rewrite ^/site/clients/^(?!login|sign-up|verify\/.*$).*$ /site/clients/index.php?action=$
}

location ~ /site/clients/^((?!login|sign-up|verify).)*$ {
   rewrite /site/clients/^((?!login|sign-up|verify).)*$ /site/clients/index.php?action=$1;
}
```

Is this even possible?
No progess has been made.

Comment: You have `/site/` part in your rewrites, but not in problem description.

Comment: That's on purpose, and is correct. I have a lemp stack on localhost and i use different folders for different projects.